Flutter requesting Location permissions - set to Aways, but getting permanently Denied
I am writing an app which I need to record a route (Strava-ish). I am using the background_locator_2 package tpo handle the background location gathering.
I am having an issue with getting the correct permissions. I am currently testing this on a physical iOS device but ultimately, will need to run on Android as well.
In Signing and capabilities, Background mode/Location is ticked.
This is part of my info.plist file
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need your location to provide the best experience, including background tracking.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need your location to track your pathway even when the app is in the background.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need your location to track your pathway.</string>
<key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
<true/>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>location</string>
</array>

My code to request permission is as follows.
Future<bool> _requestPermissions() async {    
 PermissionStatus whenInUseStatus = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.status;

 if (whenInUseStatus.isDenied) { // If denide, request it
  print("Denied - requesting locationWhenInUse permission");
  whenInUseStatus = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();
}

if (whenInUseStatus.isGranted) {
  print("LocationWhenInUse granted - requesting locationAlways permission");

  PermissionStatus alwaysStatus = await Permission.locationAlways.status;

  if (alwaysStatus.isDenied) {
    print("LocationAlways is denied - requesting permission");
    alwaysStatus = await Permission.locationAlways.request();
  }

  if (alwaysStatus.isGranted) {
    print("LocationAlways granted");
    return true;
  }

  if (alwaysStatus.isPermanentlyDenied) {
    print("LocationAlways is permanently denied. Opening app settings.");
    await openAppSettings();
    return false;
  }
}

if (whenInUseStatus.isPermanentlyDenied) {
  print("LocationWhenInUse is permanently denied. Opening app settings.");
  await openAppSettings();
  return false;
}


print("Permissions not granted - returning false");
return false;

}
I receive these messages.
flutter: Denied - requesting locationWhenInUse permission
flutter: LocationWhenInUse is permanently denied. Opening app settings.

The app settings do open, and Always is selected, but the app never seems to see this and let track
I cannot see what I am doing wrong.
